# Any way to know that a local iOS notification was displayed to the user if the user did not interact with it

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am trying to write a notification tracking system for my app. My understanding is that a scheduled local notification is guaranteed to get delivered but that my app won't get a notice that it was delivered unless the user interacts with that notification in some way. Am I missing something? Is there some event or notification sent to the app simply to indicate that the notification appeared?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you have any way of knowing about the "notification not taken."

A Jailbroken device would be a different matter.

There are silent push notifications, and I haven't looked at the new notifications API in iOS 10, so I guess it's possible Apple added a silent local notification for iOS 10...

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are 2 scenarios:

- App in background: When a local notification is delivered by the system, app is not notified, only if user interacts with notification view app is awakened.
- App in foreground: App is notified when a local notification is delivered by calling `didReceiveLocalNotification` method.

**Local notifications are guaranteed to be delivered only is user allows this (app will ask user to allow to receive local notifications)**